# Fibonacci Cyclic Pattern

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

I want to show the Fibonacci numbers are cyclic in mod n. I have tried some small values for n and I can see this is the same. In terms of a proof, I'm thinking of using the pigeonhole principle of pair of adjacent Fibonacci numbers but I think I'm going in the wrong direction.....any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: The pigeonhole principle is a good idea.  It works!  But you'll want to argue separately that if some pair recurs then (1,1) also must recur.

Comment: @lulu ok thanks for letting me know it works. I'm afraid I'm not quite on grips with the whole recur thing.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times on our site. I picked that particular instance, because it contains highly upvoted general answers that handle (in spite of the title of the question) the general modulus (not just $3$). Shame on veterans not looking for a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting $f_k:=F_k\bmod n$, you obviously have
$$f_{k+2}=(f_{k+1}+f_k)\bmod n=\phi(f_{k+1},f_k).$$

As the $f_k$ take at most $n$ different values, after at most $n^2$ steps you have exhausted all possible pairs and the iterations must cycle.

For example, with $n=3$ the sequence is

$$0,1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1\cdots$$

The function $\phi$ corresponds to the finite table

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
&\textbf0 & \textbf1 & \textbf2 \\
\textbf0&0 & 1 & 2 \\
\textbf1&1 & 2 & 0 \\
\textbf2&2 & 0 & 1 \end{array}$$

where the entry $\phi(0,0)$ is never used.

[image]

It can be shown that in fact the length of the period never exceeds $6n$.

Comment: Nice observation +1. I presume that in two dimensions, the elements of the cayley table above are isomorphic to  group $D_{3}$ the symmetry group of an equilateral triangle?

Comment: @Autolatry: yep, this is just addition modulo $n$, so it generalizes to the symmetry of regular $n$-gons.

Comment: Perfect! Then this question has a richer fabric to it then was obvious to me at the outset. Many thanks.

Comment: @Autolatry: have a look a the Pisano Period problem.

Comment: Beautiful, I had no idea of such a construction. Many thanks Yves!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the pairs $u_k=(F_{k+1} \bmod n, F_{k} \bmod n) \in M \times M$, where $M = \{ 0, 1, \dots, m-1 \}$.

Since $M \times M$ is finite (it has $m^2$ elements), it is clear that the sequence $u_k$ is *preperiodic*, that is, $u_{r+p}=u_r$ for some $r \ge 0$ and $p>0$. In other words, $u_k$ repeats with period $p$ after $k=r$.

To prove that $u_k$ is *periodic* you'll need to argue that $r=0$ works.

Comment: I should mention, I haven't come across groups yet so this proof is beyond me for now. I've been told my pigeonhole idea does work so I would prefer insight via that method as that is something I'm likely to understand. Thanks. I will upvote anyways.

Comment: @WhizKid, my argument does not use groups. I'll change the notation.